# Android: How to dynamically create a Dialog container with an imageview inside

Tags: android, android-layout, dialog, imageview

I am a hybrid apps developer and new to android. I am trying to fix an android related issue for my hybrid app.

I have the following two methods on my activity: onStart and onPause.

When the app starts I need it to start as usual. When the app is on pause, I need to show an image (my companyLogo). If I set it with setContentView(R.layout.activity_base), the image is shown when the app starts again. Is there a way to dynamically create an image, and show it  when app is on pause? Also, how do I remove the image once it starts? Since I am not hands on in Android, I am not sure how to go about it.
I suppose I need to create some sort of a Dialog and set an image view inside it.
Also, I am not sure, how to remove this image, when the app Starts again.

My code snippet:

```
public void onStart() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App is in foreground", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

public void onPause() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App is in background", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base);
}
```

Comment: onPause is called when your app goes into background, so what are you trying to do isnt really possible. Why you need that ?

Comment: When my app goes into background, I dont want it to show the current screen it is on. It should show the logo instead. When the app resumes, the logo is shown for a few seconds after which the app will start. Kind of a privacy thing

Comment: I think you are looking for Splash Screen, isn't it? [How to make Splash screen](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/)

Comment: I already have a splash screen. I need to show it when the app is in pause Mode.  I am basically trying to do what https://github.com/devgeeks/PrivacyScreenPlugin/blob/master/src/android/PrivacyScreenPlugin.java does.  Except I need a different way to do it other than setting FLAG_SECURE.

Answer (score 0):

`onResume` is called of minimize from cme to screen.
try this one

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

Comment: I need to show the image when the app is in the background. Not when it resumes.

Comment: Background image can show them used onpause method show images.

Comment: This  onresume was used remove the images u cme to foregrund then used this method.

Comment: I am not sure I understand

Answer (score 0):

```
This code is im run it. i think u need this.

inside ur  activity 


 ImageView img_view;
    TextView txt_show;
    int images[] = {R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);

        img_view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_show);
        txt_show = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_my);
    }

    private void animate(final ImageView imageView, final int images[], final int imageIndex, final boolean forever) {
        int fadeInDuration = 1000;
        int timeBetween = 5000;
        int fadeOutDuration = 1000;

        imageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        imageView.setImageResource(images[imageIndex]);

        Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);

        Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
        fadeOut.setStartOffset(fadeInDuration + timeBetween);
        fadeOut.setDuration(fadeOutDuration);

        AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
        animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
        animation.setRepeatCount(1);
        imageView.setAnimation(animation);

        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (images.length - 1 > imageIndex) {
                    animate(imageView, images, imageIndex + 1, forever);
                } else {
                    if (forever) {
                        animate(imageView, images, 0, forever);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        txt_show.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        img_view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        animate(img_view, images, 0, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        img_view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        txt_show.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }

inside ur xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_my"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="buvan"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you want will not work without FLAG_SECURE, because when you send the app in the background, the view you are viewing, is an OS-handled view and only OS has the permission to update the view. For that reason, you have to call FLAG_SECURE to notify OS that this view needs to be secured. Otherwise, changing views would have worked.

I think you got the idea.